# JQuery UI draggable set position manually

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have saved the offset X and Y to localstorage and retrieve it, then pass it to the following:

```
function SetPositionForId(id, posX, posY) {
    $("#" + id).offset({ left: posX, top: posY });
}
```

I have confirmed that the correct element is being found, but I cannot seem to set the position manually.
I have tried setting the offset, position (jquery ui), css (top and left). The values for posX and posY are also correct.

The draggable is as follows:

```
function MakeDraggableGrid() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        containment: "parent",
        grid: [300, 300]
    });
}
```

The current values for the 3 widgets are

> x and y: 582 - 47.59375

> x and y: 282 - 347.59375

> x and y: 282 - 647.59375

The HTML as seen in the inspector is as follows:

```
<div id="WidgetContainer" class="position-relative">
    <div id="d77b5dd4-4436-4c25-ba3b-5425f7d41d04" class="draggable border rounded ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: relative;">
        <div class="w-100 h-25 bg-primary p-2 pt-4">
            <h5 class="text-white">Widget #1</h5>
            <button class="btn btn-danger oi oi-x position-absolute align-self-end end-0"></button>
        </div><!--!-->
        <div class="w-100 h-75 bg-light p-2 border-primary">
            <p>eerste</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your example what you are trying to accomplish. What have you tried? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your code works "fine" to an extent: https://jsfiddle.net/8ofhLgk0/  the offset posY/posX must match a grid position, otherwise it breaks the grid layout.  In the fiddle I've used grid 100,100 and had to set the offset to 109x109.   The better alternative is to inspect your element while you use jquery-ui drag and see what it does, which is change the `inset` - so use that:  `$("#"+id).css("inset", posY + "px auto auto " + posX + "px");` https://jsfiddle.net/8ofhLgk0/1/  without a [mcve], can't really help more.

Comment: @freedomn-m I honestly don't know how I'd make a reproducible example that isn't massive but also is accurate to my situation.

I have Widgets on a [300,300] JQuery UI grid and store the position in localstorage. Everything works except setting the position.

The widgets reside in a container called #WidgetContainer and that's about it.

Comment: Did you see the two jsfiddle links in my comment above?

Comment: Yes. Both offset and Inset don't seem to do anything. I'll add the HTML as it is in the inspector to my question.